# Sort references chronologically but keep list of references in alphabetical order using model2-names.bst

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sorting

Is there any way I can modify the presort function in the model2-names.bst file so that the in-text citations can be sorted chronologically without changing the alphabetical order of citations in the list of references/bibliography? Unfortunately, I am unable to use biblatex because elsarticle.cls and other packages I am using depend on natbib.sty to use the sorting=ynt option.

```
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  ""
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
      format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" * }
            { t sortify * }
          if$
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {author.editor.sort}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { "to sort, need author, editor, or key in " cite$ * warning$
              ""
            }
            { key sortify }
          if$
        }
        { editor sort.format.names }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {editor.sort}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need editor or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { editor sort.format.names }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {presort}
{ calc.label
  label sortify
  "    "
  *
  type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.sort
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.sort
        'author.sort
      if$
    }
  if$
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.label :=
  sort.label
  *
  "    "
  *
  title field.or.null
  sort.format.title
  *
  #1 entry.max$ substring$
  'sort.key$ :=
}
```

If this is not possible, I am okay with organizing manually, but I was interested in learning how this can be modified as this is the first time I have learned of the sort function.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Let me make sure I understand your objective(s): First,  bibliographic items should be ordered alphabetically by authors' surnames (and secondarily chronologically, i.e., by publication year). Second, you want the items being cited in a citation call-out to be ordered chronologically (and secondarily alphabetically). E.g., while Jones (2020) should be listed before Smith (2010) in the formatted bibliography, a command such as `\citep{smith:2020,jones:2010}` should generate a citation call-out like `(Jones, 2010; Smith, 2020)`. Is this interpretation correct? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, that is correct Mico. 

I want the References list to be alphabetical sorting. 

But when using \citep{} or \cite{} with multiple authors, I would like them sorted chronologically.

Comment: Thanks for providing this clarification. I'm afraid that `natbib` does *not* appear to provide the functionality you say you need. To wit, if `natbib` is loaded with the option `sort` (in addition to the option `authoryear`), the arguments of `\citet` and `\citep` will be sorted *alphabetically* by the authors' surnames rather than chronologically by publication year. I guess you'll have to make a few -- luckily one-time-only -- adjustments to the ordering of the arguments of various `\citet` and `\citep` directives.

Comment: No worries! I appreciate your time! 

I think manual ordering is probably the best choice. I was just curious if this was possible, because I have seen some posts where sortify and presort functions were modified to allow this to happen for natbib, but I have not seen if for the bibliography style.